# Rails "already initialized constant LoadError::REGEXPS" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm getting an error anytime I'm creating a new app. Here is how it goes:

Running `rails new thing options` seems to work fine with no errors. (Usually the options are `-G --database=postgresql`, but the errors happen regardless.)

`rails s` starts the server, but with the error `warning: already initialized constant LoadError::REGEXPS`, `warning: previous definition of REGEXPS was here`

Visiting localhost:3000 raises the following error:

```
/Users/[username]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.3/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::Clusivity::ERROR_MESSAGE
/Users/[username]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.3/lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:6: warning: previous definition of ERROR_MESSAGE was here
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 271ms
```

(It also tells me that there's no `WelcomeController#index`, which is the thing that's generally built in.)

On a separate computer, following this exact process creates a blank Rails app.

Here is what I have tried to fix it:

- Uninstall & reinstall Rails
- Uninstall & reinstall rbenv
- brew cleanup, brew upgrade, etc.
- `gem update --system`
- `gem install bundler --pre`

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall bundler but no dice, said it was in a different GEM_HOME. Not sure why that would be.

I have Ruby 2.4.1 and Rails 5.1.3.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this error would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify: This error happens on a new, blank Rails app (no custom code, no models, etc) right after creating the Rails app with `rails new ...`? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If you (instead of following the same steps to create a new project on the other computer) commit the project generated on computer A into version control and check it out on computer B, does the error still exist or does it work? What command (exactly) and what options do you use to generate the new project? Is the OS the same on both machines?

Comment: A new project created on my machine works on other machines, even though it doesn't on mine. OS is the same on both (Mac). Same version of ruby, rbenv, etc.

Comment: If you create a new project on your machine without any options - just the defaults - something like `rails new foo`, does that new project show the same behavior and error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of two things:

- The system username was camelcased
- The whole user folder was, weirdly, living in iCloud

The issue was solved by creating a new admin user and turning off the iCloud feature.